# find column value and name based on minimum value in other column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table that looks like this

```
library( data.table )

dt <- data.table( p1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"), 
                  p2 = c("b", "c", "d", "a", "f", "g", "h"), 
                  p3 = c("z", "x", NA, NA, "y", NA, "s"), 
                  t1 = c(1, 2, 3, NA, 5, 6, 7), 
                  t2 = c(7, 6, 5, NA, 3, 2, NA), 
                  t3 = c(8, 3, NA, NA, 2, NA, 1) )

#    p1 p2   p3 t1 t2 t3
# 1:  a  b    z  1  7  8
# 2:  b  c    x  2  6  3
# 3:  c  d <NA>  3  5 NA
# 4:  d  a <NA> NA NA NA
# 5:  e  f    y  5  3  2
# 6:  f  g <NA>  6  2 NA
# 7:  g  h    s  7 NA  1
```

It has p-columns, representing names, and t-columns, representing values.
t1 is the value corresponding to p1, t2 to p2, etc..
On each row, values of p-columns are unique (or `NA`). The same goes for the values in the t-columns.

What I want to do is to create three new columns:

- `t_min`, the minimum value of all t-columns for each row (exclude NA's)
- `p_min`, if t_min exists (is not NA), the corresponding value of the p-column...  so if the t2-column has the t-min value, the corresponding value of column `p2`.
- `p_col_min`, the name of the column with the value if p_min. So if the p_min value comes from colum `p2`, then "p2".

I prefer a `data.table`, since my actual data contains a **lot** more rows and columns. I know melting is an option, but I would like to preserve my memory with this data, so lesser memory used is better (production data contains several million rows and >200 columns).

So far I've found a way to create the `t_min`-column using the following:

```
t_cols = dt[ , .SD, .SDcols = grep( "t[1-3]", names( dt ), value = TRUE ) ]
dt[ !all( is.na( t_cols ) ), 
    t_min := do.call( pmin, c( .SD, list( na.rm = TRUE ) ) ), 
    .SDcols = names( t_cols ) ]
```

But I cannot wrap my head around creating the `p_min` and `p_col_min` columns. I suppose `which.min()` comes into play somewhere, but I cannot figure it out. Probably something simple I'm overlooking (it always seems to be.. ;-) ).

**desired output**

```
dt.desired <- data.table( p1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"), 
                          p2 = c("b", "c", "d", "a", "f", "g", "h"), 
                          p3 = c("z", "x", NA, NA, "y", NA, "s"), 
                          t1 = c(1, 2, 3, NA, 5, 6, 7), 
                          t2 = c(7, 6, 5, NA, 3, 2, NA), 
                          t3 = c(8, 3, NA, NA, 2, NA, 1),
                          t_min = c(1,2,3,NA,2,2,1),
                          p_min = c("a","b","c",NA,"y","g","s"),
                          p_col_min = c("p1","p1","p1",NA,"p3","p2","p3") )

#    p1 p2   p3 t1 t2 t3 t_min p_min p_col_min
# 1:  a  b    z  1  7  8     1     a        p1
# 2:  b  c    x  2  6  3     2     b        p1
# 3:  c  d <NA>  3  5 NA     3     c        p1
# 4:  d  a <NA> NA NA NA    NA  <NA>      <NA>
# 5:  e  f    y  5  3  2     2     y        p3
# 6:  f  g <NA>  6  2 NA     2     g        p2
# 7:  g  h    s  7 NA  1     1     s        p3
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot guarantee whether this is a solution efficient enough for your working data, but this is what I would try first:

```
m1 <- as.matrix(dt[, grep('^t', names(dt)), with = FALSE])
m2 <- as.matrix(dt[, grep('^p', names(dt)), with = FALSE])

t_min <- apply(m1, 1, min, na.rm = TRUE)
t_min[is.infinite(t_min)] <- NA_real_
p_min_index <- rep(NA_integer_, length(t_min))
p_min_index[!is.na(t_min)] <- apply(m1[!is.na(t_min), ], 1, which.min)

dt[, t_min  := t_min]
dt[, p_min := m2[cbind(seq_len(nrow(m2)), p_min_index)] ]
dt[, p_min_col := grep('^p', names(dt), value = TRUE)[p_min_index] ]


#    p1 p2   p3 t1 t2 t3 t_min p_min p_min_col
# 1:  a  b    z  1  7  8     1     a        p1
# 2:  b  c    x  2  6  3     2     b        p1
# 3:  c  d <NA>  3  5 NA     3     c        p1
# 4:  d  a <NA> NA NA NA    NA  <NA>      <NA>
# 5:  e  f    y  5  3  2     2     y        p3
# 6:  f  g <NA>  6  2 NA     2     g        p2
# 7:  g  h    s  7 NA  1     1     s        p3
```

In addition, It looks like that the 2nd row in your desired output is incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

A simple and efficient approach is to loop through the "t*" columns and track all respective values in a single pass.

First initialize appropriate vectors:

```
p.columns = which(startsWith(names(dt), "p"))
t.columns = which(startsWith(names(dt), "t"))

p_col_min = integer(nrow(dt))
p_min = character(nrow(dt))
t_min = rep_len(Inf, nrow(dt))
```

and iterate while updating:

```
for(i in seq_along(p.columns)) {
    cur.min = which(dt[[t.columns[i]]] < t_min)

    p_col_min[cur.min] = p.columns[i]

    t_min[cur.min] = dt[[t.columns[i]]][cur.min]
    p_min[cur.min] = dt[[p.columns[i]]][cur.min]
}
```

Finally fill with `NA`s where needed:

```
whichNA = is.infinite(t_min)
is.na(t_min) = is.na(p_min) = is.na(p_col_min) = whichNA

t_min
#[1]  1  2  3 NA  2  2  1
p_min
#[1] "a" "b" "c" NA  "y" "g" "s"
p_col_min
#[1]  1  1  1 NA  3  2  3
```

Comment: not a big fan of `for`-loops personally. but thank you for your approach.. much appreciated!

Comment: @Wimpel : Are you concerned about efficiency? If so, I'd encourage to .."give for-loops a chance". The current for-loop, here, 1) is a simple `length(<columns starting with "t">)` repeat of simple and efficient operations ("<", "which", "[", "[<-") and 2) avoids using any additional memory with any (non "list-like" (data.table)) large temporary objects.

Comment: I guess p_min could be filled with final values outside the loop (instead of overwriting in the loop) since it doesn't affect cur.min, eg `is.na(p_col_min) <- p_col_min == 0; dt[, pm := if (is.na(p_col_min)) NA_character_ else .SD[[p_col_min]], by=p_col_min]$pm`

Comment: @Frank2 : Yes, I think that's a nice approach to subset the p-columns after retrieving the minima (and their p-indices). It, also, seems that the "by" evaluations (in "[.data.table") won't be a bottleneck, having in mind that the number of p-columns (and, so, the distinct values of "p_col_min") is only a few hundred.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another route:

```
dt[, t_min := do.call(pmin, c(.SD, na.rm = TRUE)), .SDcols = patterns('t[[:digit:]]')]

dt[!is.na(t_min),
   c('p_min', 'p_min_col') := {

     arr_ind = .SD[, which(t_min == .SD, arr.ind = TRUE), .SDcols = patterns('t[[:digit:]]')]
     arr_ind = arr_ind[order(arr_ind[, 1]), ]

     p_m = .SD[, as.matrix(.SD)[arr_ind], .SDcols = patterns('p')]
     p_m_c = grep('^p', names(.SD), value = TRUE)[arr_ind[, 2]]

     list(p_m, p_m_c)
     } 
   ]
```

Comment: thanks.. also for reminding me that `.SDcols` can use `patterns` (almost since a year now, but somehow I forgot)...

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option:

```
ri <- dt[, .I[rowSums(is.na(.SD))==ncol(.SD)], .SDcols=t1:t3]

dt[-ri, c("t_min", "p_min", "p_col_min") := {
        pmat <- .SD[, .SD, .SDcols=p1:p3]
        tmat <- as.matrix(.SD[, .SD, .SDcols=t1:t3])

        i <- max.col(-replace(tmat, is.na(tmat), Inf), "first")

        y <- cbind(seq_len(.N), i)

        .(t_min = tmat[y],
            p_min = as.matrix(pmat)[y],
            p_col_min = names(pmat)[i])
    }]
dt
```

output:

```
   p1 p2   p3 t1 t2 t3 t_min p_min p_col_min
1:  a  b    z  1  7  8     1     a        p1
2:  b  c    x  2  6  3     2     b        p1
3:  c  d <NA>  3  5 NA     3     c        p1
4:  d  a <NA> NA NA NA    NA  <NA>      <NA>
5:  e  f    y  5  3  2     2     y        p3
6:  f  g <NA>  6  2 NA     2     g        p2
7:  g  h    s  7 NA  1     1     s        p3
```

Comment: +1, I was about to change my array indices to the exact same thing as your ```i``` and ```y```. While there are ```data.table``` solutions, it would be so much easier if ```data.table``` could take a matrix for subsetting.

Comment: @Cole i think S. Ritchie is working on something on github/rdatatable